# Finding the index of the largest element of an array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I am a very inexperienced programmer and have picked up C# as my starting language. For now I am scripting on Unity and I just have a small question.

Is there a way to call out the index of the largest variable in an array simply, I found C# to have a lot of practical shortcuts and I was wondering if there is an *arrayName*.max() equivalent which would return that index.

Also if you wonder yes I know a way of doing it with code, I'm just wondering if you can call it as fast as you can call .max().

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please read [ask]; it helps to search, and show what you have tried.

Comment: arr.Max(item => item);